# For $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, $\exists \Sigma$, s.t. $A \notin \Sigma$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

For any set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, there exists a sigma algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $A \notin \Sigma$.

---

Is this true or false?

I would think false because we can easily choose $A= \mathbb R$ but every sigma algebra of the reals will contain the reals so it cant be true right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You could also say that $\emptyset \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and every $\sigma$ algebra contains $\emptyset$.

However, if $A\neq \Bbb{R}$ and $A\neq \emptyset$ then just consider the trivial $\sigma$ algebra $\{\Bbb{R},\emptyset\}$.